# What is the word to say you have to take your medicine?

Tags: word-choice

In Portuguese we can use the word `toma` to say the time you have to take your medicine.

Example: "Às 4 horas da tarde é a hora da toma de medicamentos, para Paulo", meaning, "At 4pm is the `drug taking time` for Paulo".

I need to create an Excel sheet and one of the columns should be `Toma` or the equivalent in English, and will represent the time patients have to take their medicines.

What is the best term to mean that in English?

Comment: In English, we would just say take, for instance 'at [insert time of taking], I have to take my medicine.'

Comment: I don't know that there's a single word for this, but **dosage time** is a short phrase that describes this concept.

Comment: @CanadianYankee - will that cover if the prescription is an injection? What about "prescription time"?

Comment: A **dose** or **dosage** is any measured amount of a medicine taken at one particular time, whether it's taken orally or injected.  The time when the **dosage** is administered is the **dosage time**.

Comment: A prescription is either a written or printed document issued by a doctor and exchanged for medication at a pharmacy, or the medication itself.

Comment: ahhh, fantastic explanation guys!!!!

Comment: @CanadianYankee, please make this dosage comment an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Gathering up a few things from the comments:

A [**prescription**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prescription) is the full set of instructions issued by a doctor or other medical professional that is given to the pharmacist (or sent to them electronically) that authorizes the distribution of the medicine.  A **prescription** can also mean the full amount of the medicine issued as a result of the doctor's prescription.

One thing the prescription will specify is the [**dosage regimen**](https://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/dosage+regimen), which is defined at the link I've given here as:

> The schedule of doses of a therapeutic agent per unit of time, including: the time between doses (e.g., every 6 hours) or the time when the dose(s) are to be given (e.g., at 8 a.m. and 4 p.m. daily), and the amount of a medicine (e.g., number of capsules) to be given at each specific time.

You can use the modifier **dosage** to specify any part of that regimen:

- **Dosage frequency** is how often the medicine is administered, like "three times per day."
- **Dosage time** is time(s) when it's administered.
- **Dosage timing** could be instructions like "before each meal" that are less precise than specific times.
- **Dosage amount** (or just **dose**) is the quantity administered at one time.
- **Dosage form** is the physical form of the medicine (pill, capsule, injection, etc.).

In the context of a spreadsheet, you might be able to leave off the repeated "dosage", especially if you can put "dosage regimen" in a heading over all parts of the regimen.